# Background Image not loading on heroku open

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

When deploying my app on heroku my background image is not showing up..

My Logo image does show up though.

They are both in my assets/images file

My background is referenced in my assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss file:

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    background: url('city-lights1.jpg');
}
```

And my Logo is referenced in my views/layouts/pages/home file:

```
<div class='log-image'>
        <%= image_tag("logo.png", alt: "image", class:'img-responsive logo') %>
</div>
```

Why does my background image not load but my logo image does?

**I'm using twitter bootstrap**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the Rails helpers in your **application.scss** as you did in your home page, so the url of the background image is not referencing the image as expected.

You should use the rails 4 helper in your **application.scss** file:

```
background-image: asset-url("city-lights1.jpg");
/* Or */
background-image: image-url("city-lights1.jpg");
```

Also, you can reference the asset directly (Note that you don't need to include the **/image** folder in the url). Keep in mind that this url reference is not going to work in Heroku if you precompile your assets:

```
background-image: url("/assets/city-lights1.jpg");
```

There's more detailed information about how to reference images within the assets pipeline on the [Rails' Official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass).

Comment: I ended up using something similar and got it to work: background: image-url('city-lights1.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous solution, you will need this:
Make sure you set these in your production.rb file

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```